# Let’s remove the tag from [where] this [clause] comes from

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

It seems that we have one of the [visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual)[studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/studio) tags pairs. [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where) and [clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clause) were (?) created at the same time, and they were a typo that went out of control looking for [where-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where-clause) for SQL questions and now it's our chore to clean it up.

1. No
2. No
3. No, they were created as a pair.
4. No, well, kinda yes? Define "context".

Sadly, both tags were allowed to reach >50, since the old times.

Comment: Before someone complains "they are two tags!" these tags were created in pairs. One cannot ask for the removal of one of the tags without asking for the removal of the other.

Comment: [[tag:where]] is already a synonym of [[tag:where-clause]]

Comment: @CodyGray that seems to be very inappropriate. Not every question with the where tag was about sql-like features https://stackoverflow.com/q/63046213/792066 https://stackoverflow.com/q/63059007/792066 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62995469/792066

Comment: More examples here of potential questions with the [where-clause] tag that may not have sql features https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/where-clause+-mysql+-sql+-sql-server+-postgresql+-sqlite+-tsql+-sql-server-2008+-mysqli+-plsql+-sql-server-2005+-apache-spark-sql+-sqlalchemy+-sql-server-2012+-linq-to-sql+-sql-server-2008-r2+-nosql+-sql-update+-android-sqlite+-azure-sql-database+-sql-order-by

Comment: Agreed. But that synonym was created way back in 2011, so all of those questions you mention actually were tagged [where-clause], not [where]... :-(

Comment: @CodyGray you sure? I didn't notice that... :/ ... sigh...

Comment: Yep. I checked the moderator tag synonym tool. It was definitely created back in 2011. The tags were not merged, because it wasn't created by a moderator, just by the normal (broken) community tag suggestion process.

Comment: So, when the clause tag came to my attention, I figured that it was probably someone trying to type where-clause and effectively, the oldest question with the [clause tag also had the where tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317606/how-to-do-a-where-in-clause-in-linqtosql) But the system doesn't show you the synonym immediately, only *after* editing. So, this request was written with that supposition: that there were two independent tags.